# Python: would this leave me with a clean environment?

Tags: python, namespaces, read-eval-print-loop

I want to change directories in the python (not ipython) repl under certain circumstances.

If I programmatically send the following text will I be likely to avoid any name pollution?

```
import os as prefix_hide_os
prefix_hide_os.chdir("/some/path)
del prefix_hide_os
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this

```
__import__("os").chdir("/some/path")
```